# Intent data not updated in activity while launched from andorid push notification click

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification

I am using Google cloud messaging for my android application.GCM part is running successfully.Now I want to show the message in a UI activity when the user taps on the notification icon in the status bar.

I am launching my **ResultShowActivity** from the notification using the following code.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ResultShowActivity.class);
   notificationIntent.putExtra("Message",msg);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm_cloud)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

The message is being sent properly,and shown correctly when the GCM notification appears but when I capture the extras of intent in **ResultShowActivity** it is always showing the old message.
I am using following code to receive message from intent in ResultShowActivity.

```
String GCMMsg = showViewIntent.getStringExtra("Message");
```

I have tried removing the in ResultShowActivity by using

```
intent.removeExtra("Message");
```

or

```
intent.replaceExtras(extras);
```

Can anyone please suggest how to retrieve the updated message from intent.Thanks for any help regarding this.

Comment: In newer version of android I found the same issues, following changes helped me. 
check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70227216/5664529

Answer (score 2):

Please use following code

```
int iUniqueId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);


PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,iUniqueId,notificationIntent, 0);
```

Instead of following line of code

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Excellent tip. Thks  a lot ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP** to intent flag and **PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT** to pending intent flag.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,YourActivity.class);

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

#### **Important:** Make sure to implement `onNewIntent(Intent intent)`. This function will be called when your activity is in foreground.