# Android 12 Pending Intent Immutable flag not available under API 23

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-12

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045607/how-to-resolve-missing-pendingintent-mutability-flag-lint-warning-in-android-a), but not the same

After update to Android 12 (SDK 31) we change `PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)` to `PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)` like [suggested](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12).

But `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` is not available for SDK under 23. If I add `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)` to keep both versions, I stay with the lint warning about not using the correct flag for the `else` case.

What is the expected behaviour here? Thanks!

Comment: If you have the version check then you can choose to either ignore the lint warning or suppress it

Comment: @tyczj indeed, but I hope there is the right way fo doing it, that is not ignore/suppress.

Comment: that is the right way of doing it, IDE is not smart enough to know you handled the scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE`:

> Up until Build.VERSION_CODES.R, PendingIntents are assumed to be mutable by default, unless FLAG_IMMUTABLE is set. Starting with Build.VERSION_CODES.S, it will be required to explicitly specify the mutability of PendingIntents on creation with either FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE. It is strongly recommended to use FLAG_IMMUTABLE when creating a PendingIntent. FLAG_MUTABLE should only be used when some functionality relies on modifying the underlying intent, e.g. any PendingIntent that needs to be used with inline reply or bubbles.

In summary, you should add the `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` flag to your PendingIntent when targeting API 31 or later, unless you need your PendingIntent to be mutable, in which case you need to use `FLAG_MUTABLE`.

Because `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` was introduced in API 23, you have to use `FLAG_MUTABLE` as a fallback for lower versions.

```kotlin
val flag =
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
  else PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
```

You can combine this with your existing intent flags, if you have any, using a bitwise [or](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/or.html) operation. For example:

```kotlin
val flags = flag or PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
```

Comment: val flag =
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
  else PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
this code will not solve the OP's problem as PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE was first introduced in api level 31 so it cannot be used for lower versions (<23 /Build.VERSION_CODES.M in this case) as @Noah mentioned in his answer. Lint will keep giving the warning.

Comment: My apps widget is not working in Samsung galaxy models version 11 and 12. I don't have any idea, why it is freezing now PendingIntent launchAppActionPending = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            launchAppActionPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, launchAppAction,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        } else {
            launchAppActionPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, launchAppAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); }

Comment: `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` is not available for API levels below 31. Can't understand why this answer is the accepted one.

Answer (score 6):

I just got the same problem, here is how i fixed it:

```kotlin
val flags =
  if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
  } else {
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
  }

  return Intent(context, TastingReceiver::class.java).let { intent ->
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TASTING_ID, tasting.id)
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    context,
    tasting.id.hashCode(),
    intent,
    flags
   )
}
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: I dont really know why tbh, this just a way to put it that the IDE doesn't complain with

Answer (score -4):

You can simply ignore the warning: on APIs levels under 23, the flag will simply be ignored (tested on API 21).