# Missing PendingIntent mutability flag giving warning after checking sdk version

Tags: android, kotlin, warnings, android-pendingintent

Hey I am getting warning for pending intent. So I surrounded for check of checking sdk according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67045607/11560810) and this [medium](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/all-about-pendingintents-748c8eb8619) post. I am getting warning message
**Missing `PendingIntent` mutability flag**

```
val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            } else {
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            }
```

[image]

How can I remove this warning message?

[image]

Comment: That looks like a bug in the Lint check, as your code appears to be fine.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah I don't get it why this is giving warning :(

Comment: @vivekmodi Were you able to figure out a reason?  I am using WorkManger version 2.7.1

Comment: @vivekmodi we are suppressing it by adding `@SuppressLint("UnspecifiedImmutableFlag")` to the method but that doesn't seem very satisfying! Agreed that the linter should give this a pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems OK, and I believe it's a bug in the Lint check as it's been
stated by @CommonsWare in comments. This could be fixed in the next releases of Android Studio

> How can I remove this warning message?

If you just want to remove the annoying warning there is a hack in building the condition that clear the warning: by transferring the conditional to the flag:

```
val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this,
    0,
    intent,
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    else PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
)
```

Or at the worse case you'd suppress it by `@SuppressLint("UnspecifiedImmutableFlag")`, which I don't recommend.

Answer (score 2):

Add pending intent like this

```
val updatedPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
applicationContext,
NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE,
updatedIntent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT )
```

If the error still remains and your **targetSdkVersion = 31** then the error must caused because one of your dependencies is internally using WorkManager or your are directly using old version of WorkManager.
To solve simply add this dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
```

Comment: I already added this library in my project.

Comment: @MuhammadAsad his `minSdkVersion` is 21 so a different linter warning comes up when using `FLAG_IMMUTABLE`. Also the linter warning is raised specifically on the lines of code in the question.