# Android 12 Pending Intent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-pendingintent

**Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.     Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable**

I can't update the pending intent flag in android studio project coding

This is a place in AlarmPingSender.java where the error occurred

```
  public void start()        
   {       
   String action = MqttServiceConstants.PING_SENDER
            + comms.getClient().getClientId();
    Log.d(TAG, "Register alarmreceiver to MqttService"+ action);
    service.registerReceiver(alarmReceiver, new IntentFilter(action));

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(service, 0, new Intent(
            action), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    schedule(comms.getKeepAlive());
    hasStarted = true;
}
```

*Help me to fix the issue* **[ERROR IN ANDROID STUDIO IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qlGE.jpg)**

Comment: Any one please help

Comment: The error message tells you pretty much exactly what to do. Also there are numerous questions on Stackoverflow covering this exact problem. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#DeclareMutabilityPendingIntent

Comment: i don't know exactly where to change the pending intent on the code we have tried a lot methods and various place in code but its not working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this two public methods when you want to create any `PendingIntent` in your project

Create activity pendingIntent

```
   public static PendingIntent createPendingIntentGetActivity(Context context, int id, Intent intent, int flag) {
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
             return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | flag);
         } else {
             return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intent, flag);
         }
     }
```

Create broadcast pendingIntent

```
 public static PendingIntent createPendingIntentGetBroadCast(Context context, int id, Intent intent, int flag) {
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
         return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | flag);
     } else {
         return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, flag);
     }
 }
```

**Kotlin answer:**

```
fun getActivity(context: Context?, id: Int, intent: Intent?, flag: Int): PendingIntent {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE or flag)
    } else {
        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intent, flag)
    }
}

fun getBroadcast(context: Context?, id: Int, intent: Intent?, flag: Int): PendingIntent {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent!!, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE or flag)
    } else {
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent!!, flag)
    }
}
```

Comment: why Version M? M is Api 23 ?

Comment: I edit the answer, change skd to S+

Comment: @ShahabSaalami I think it should be M only for FLAG_IMMUTABLE( was introduced in api 23).

Answer (score 6):

You need to do this:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(service, 0, new Intent(
        action), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT |
                 PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

Since you are using `AlarmManager` you should be able to use the `IMMUTABLE` flag.

Comment: sir can i know the exact place we need to use this code , As we have tried this already its not working for us .  We worked in AlarmPingIntent to change this

Comment: [App Coding](https://drive.google.com/file/d/121gVQJASqxXPrFb2KfJoZfbB-tzK_1rO/view?usp=sharing)      The link contains coding of  the demo application which we created based on the exact concept we used kindly help in this @[David Wasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/769265/david-wasser)

Comment: Have you seen this? Are you using the same MQTT library? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71155187/android-paho-mqtt-crashes-android-12-targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requi

Comment: Will work and let u know sir i think its as same as what we got

Comment: There is a link to another version of the library in that ticket that may solve your problem.

Comment: ok sir lets try it

Comment: Were you able to fix your problem with the linked solution?

Comment: yes sir but it is in kotlin format we use java

Comment: What is in Kotlin format? What did you do to fix the problem?

Comment: sir can u give us a step by step procedure for the fixing of the problem

Comment: @David Wasser Can you expand on your comment to "...probably need to use the MUTABLE flag." with Alarm Manager?  I use AlarmManager to fire alarms to trigger Notifications for user due dates and am wondering if I should be using MUTABLE flag.

Comment: @AJW Reviewing my comment, I assumed that `AlarmManager` was adding something to the `Intent` when it was triggered, which would imply that `FLAG_MUTABLE` was necessary. However, I just looked again and `AlarmManager` doesn't add anything to the `Intent`, so you should be safe using `FLAG_IMMUTABLE`. Sorry for the confusion. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @David Wasser No apology necessary, thanks for reviewing and clarifying.  I did see in Android Developer guide that MUTABLE can be used if you have a repeating alarm, to allow the EXTRA_ALARM_COUNT intent extra but only for that use case:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#DeclareMutabilityPendingIntent

Comment: @AJW Generally speaking you need to use `FLAG_MUTABLE` if you give the `PendingIntent` to another app and that app needs to add/modify the `Intent` when it ultimately triggers the `PendingIntent`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and adding JUST the IMMUTABLE flag to my PendingIntents did not work for some reason.

Please make sure that in app/build.gradle, you have at least the 2.7.1 work manager version (If you're also using WorkManager inside the app):

implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'

I had 1.0.3. After upgrading to this (or latest version), the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using `PendingIntent` anywhere in your code but still get this error, chances are that one of your library dependencies does so just update your dependencies to their latest versions (its what worked for me)