# Android 12 Kotlin - Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification

This is the code for pendingIntent:

```
val pi =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
        applicationContext,
        0,
        ii,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
```

I'm getting this error when using it:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: de.xxx.xxx: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

I still need the activity to be updated so how can I add this `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` or `FLAG_MUTABLE` what ever the hell this is and still be able to update the activity? Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70889493/android-12-pending-intent) answer I tried:

```
val pi =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
        applicationContext,
        0,
        ii,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
```

but this gives syntax error!

So how should the code look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on this answer

The code presently shown in that question and answer are in Java. You are writing in Kotlin.

In Kotlin, use [the `or` bitwise operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#bitwise-operations):

```kotlin
val pi =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
        applicationContext,
        0,
        ii,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
```

Comment: Android 12 includes important changes to pending intents, including a change that requires explicitly deciding when a PendingIntent is mutable or immutable. Read [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/all-about-pendingintents-748c8eb8619) great article for detailed information

Comment: any PendingIntents created without the FLAG_IMMUTABLE flag were implicitly mutable