# NFC pendingIntent

Tags: android, nfc, lib-nfc

Just to ask what is this issue that is appearing with android studio when i entered with NFC onCreate() method where the flag i input is 0 but is stated to insert pendingIntent, im not sure what does it means?

```
    NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        //nfc not support your device.
        return;
    }
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
            getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

    }
```

> Problem:Missing `PendingIntent` mutability flag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android 12 Pending Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70889493/android-12-pending-intent)

Comment: For NFC the Pending Intent should be FLAG_MUTABLE . You could of course use the newer and better `enableReaderMode` NFC API to handle NFC events which does not need Intents.