# Application crashes in Android 12 and S versions because of PendingIntent

Tags: android, kotlin

I know there are multiple answers to these questions, I tried them all which were suggested in other StackOverflow posts, such as

- Using FlagImmutable, I changed all of the flags of PendingIntents
- used the work-manager library in my app module, the stable one
- Updated FireBase
  But still, application crashes in Android 12 and I get the following error:
  **Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.**

Comment: Have a look at the stacktrace to learn where exactly the pendingintent is used. It is likely created somewhere nearby. It might be yet another library you need to update.

Comment: Using google analytics instead of firebase analytics might be an issue

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan I'm using FireBase analytics

Comment: @laalto I got D/com.facebook.FacebookSdk: getGraphApiVersion: v12.0 such line after run and crash, can this one be a reason?

Comment: crash stacktrace is E error log level, not D debug

Comment: Oh yeah. Thank you.                                                                 E/com.facebook.GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1703607243113464' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045607/how-to-resolve-missing-pendingintent-mutability-flag-lint-warning-in-android-a

Comment: @ManishGorkha I tried them all, unfortunately not working (