# FLUTTER : Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depend

Tags: android, flutter

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.ex.app: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
```

E/AndroidRuntime(16660): Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

Comment: Does it help you to get over it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72238069/10659482

Comment: And please write something more than logs. Describe if there is an error or bug. Btw, this is not an error.

Comment: this question is already answered here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68473542/mediasessioncompattargeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag