# React native app crashing on android 12+ on emulator

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am currently working on building a music app `Wavelet`.
Here's my dependencies:
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/759CO.png)

I usually debug on an Android 11 emulator, but when using an Android 12 emulator and my physical device on Android 12L it crashes.

I was able to pick [this log](https://bin.kv2.dev/%7E6255602a410e7c32e669bc5a) from my physical device.

Comment: Well, the error log is pretty clear: "Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent." Android 12 is API 31, did you try setting FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE ?

Comment: I have no idea where to set it, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045607/how-to-resolve-missing-pendingintent-mutability-flag-lint-warning-in-android-a) but couldn't understand where to add.

Answer (score 6):

Go into `build.gradle` and find `dependencies`

Look for `androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx...`

Add or update it to:

```
// fix for crash API 31
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0"
```

Comment: I can't believe it! That that one line is all it took (I think) to get a react native app to stop crashing and be able to submit to play store. Thank you so much!