# Android release crash with exception net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException

Tags: android, proguard, crash-reports, sqlcipher-android, release-apk

I've uploaded my app to play store but it still crashes as "**crash report image**" of developer console shows.

on some devices the app did not lunch at all

while on other it crashes when start sql query

btw proguard is disabled

**crash report image**
[image: crash report image]

**the query method**
[image: query]

Answer (score -1):

There are two main crash exceptions

#### 1. SQLiteException

and I've solved this by comment the proguardfiles in **Build.gradle** as follow

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

#### 2. illegalargumentexception

If you let your app to run in android 12 and app has notification feature, there is a new PendingIntent mutability flag

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        //pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
}
else{
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

- for more details [How to resolve "Missing PendingIntent mutability flag" lint warning in android api 30+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045607/how-to-resolve-missing-pendingintent-mutability-flag-lint-warning-in-android-a)