# xamarin forms : Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

When i run the application  android OS 11 and below it is working but it not working Android os 12 when i deploy the application the following run time exception im getting.

```
[AndroidRuntime] Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:651)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:638)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zzd(Unknown Source:18)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zzb(Unknown Source:229)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zza(Unknown Source:0)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzj.zzb(Unknown Source:41)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzj.getToken(Unknown Source:56)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getToken(Unknown Source:10)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zzcfy(Unknown Source:4)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source:148)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.handleIntent(Unknown Source:122)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source:4)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Kindly help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you can debug to find which `PendingIntent` you used caused this error.

If it is created by yourself, you can try to set the flag as `PendingIntentFlags.Immutable` or the `PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent` when you use the `PendingIntent`. For more information, you can check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045607/how-to-resolve-missing-pendingintent-mutability-flag-lint-warning-in-android-a).

And if it is created by the nuget packages you used, you can try to upgrade the package's version to the newest one.

In addition, the library mentioned in the case's answer I provided above. It is the nuget package named `Xamarin.AndroidX.Work.Runtime` in the xamarin, you can install the last version in your project.

Comment: My pleasure, and looking forward to your reply. @neha

Comment: ```Xamarin.AndroidX.Work.Runtime``` still facing same issue.` if (global::Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= global::Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
                {
                    NotificationImportance importance = global::Android.App.NotificationImportance.Default;
                     pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable); else
                {
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Mutable);

                }` and installed Work.runtime still  same issue

Comment: Sorry for my careless, the package doesn't need in your project. According to the error message, the packages about the firebase caused this error. Did you update these packages to the newest version? @neha

Comment: Thanks for advice @Liyun Zhang After update firebase packages now the application working.

Comment: @neha can you give me the list of plugins and their versions you used in your project to resolve this issue????

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by upgrading my Firebase packages.
You might need to update Xamarin.Forms too.