# How to fix pending intent warning

Tags: android, warnings, immutability, android-pendingintent

Missing `PendingIntent` mutability flag ---> this is the warning in my android kotlin project. I am using headsup notification in it. In this, while setting pending intent, if i set 0  to pending intent content [val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)] , Missing "`PendingIntent` mutability flag" warning arised.
If i use pending intent. FLAG_IMMUTABLE, my project getting error after i have released my app bundle in google play console. error--- [Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles]. What should i use in the notifications. I am using API level 26. Can anyone help me please.

```
    private fun createNotification(title: String, description: String) {
    val s = "Messages"

    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)

    intent.putExtra("fragmsg", s)
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

    val pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)

    val notificationManager =
        applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val notificationChannel =
            NotificationChannel("101", "channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.BLUE
        notificationChannel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
      //  notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)

    }

    val notificationBuilder  =NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "101")
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(description)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logof)
        .setPriority(PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setOngoing(false)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)

    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())

}
```

Comment: Maybe this link could help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045607/how-to-resolve-missing-pendingintent-mutability-flag-lint-warning-in-android-a

If you use firebase, try update it.

Answer (score 1):

```
val pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
   this,
   0,
   intent,
   PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT // setting the mutability flag 
)
```

According to the docs here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#pending-intent-mutability

```
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

Choose your flag accordingly.

If you want to read more about this i would suggest that you read this great article here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/all-about-pendingintents-748c8eb8619

Comment: Same issue arising.  its not fixed when i use above one. please any other method to solve this pending intent issue?