# FCM notifications crash app, Android 13 notifications not showing

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
private const val CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel"

class FirebaseService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    companion object {
        var sharedPref: SharedPreferences? = null

        var token: String?
            get() {
                return sharedPref?.getString("token", "")
            }
            set(value) {
                sharedPref?.edit()?.putString("token", value)?.apply()
            }
    }

    override fun onNewToken(newToken: String) {
        super.onNewToken(newToken)
        token = newToken
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val notificationID = Random.nextInt()

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createNotificationChannel(notificationManager)
        }

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(message.data["title"])
            .setContentText(message.data["message"])
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_foreground)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification)

    }
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createNotificationChannel(notificationManager: NotificationManager) {
        val channelName = "channelName"
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channelName, IMPORTANCE_HIGH).apply {
            description = "My channel description"
            enableLights(true)
            lightColor = Color.GREEN
        }
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

}
```

I attempted to modify the code, but unfortunately, my changes did not resolve the issue I am encountering. I was wondering if you might have any suggestions on what else I can try to resolve this problem.

Comment: If you're crashing, post the stack trace.

Comment: This question already has answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67046334/8190327