# PendingIntent with FLAG_MUTABLE risk examples?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

As stated in the [PendingIntent section](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/risks/pending-intent#risk_mutable_pending_intents) of the `Mitigate security risks in your app` in the Android Developer documentation, an application that receives a PendingIntent can modify `unfilled fields of a PendingIntent to allow access to otherwise non-exported components of the vulnerable application`:

> Risk: Mutable Pending Intents
>
> A PendingIntent can be mutable, which means that the inner intent that
> specifies the action can be updated by application B following the
> logic described in the fillIn() documentation. In other words, the
> unfilled fields of a PendingIntent can be modified by a malicious app
> and allow access to otherwise non-exported components of the
> vulnerable application.

Because of this risk they created a Lint warning for app sources that use PendingIntents without mutability flag, as posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045607/how-to-resolve-missing-pendingintent-mutability-flag-lint-warning-in-android-a)

Can you show an example or a real use case of how such risk could be exploited?

Code snippets help understanding and are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Sample Code

```
val updatedPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
   context,
   NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE,
   updatedIntent,
   PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT 
)
```

> Up until Build.VERSION_CODES.R, PendingIntents are assumed to be
> mutable by default, unless FLAG_IMMUTABLE is set. Starting with
> Build.VERSION_CODES.S, it will be required to explicitly specify the
> mutability of PendingIntents on creation with either (FLAG_IMMUTABLE}
> or FLAG_MUTABLE. It is strongly recommended to use FLAG_IMMUTABLE when
> creating a PendingIntent. FLAG_MUTABLE should only be used when some
> functionality relies on modifying the underlying intent, e.g. any
> PendingIntent that needs to be used with inline reply or bubbles.

Comment: I was asking for an example of a code snippet that could exploit the mentioned risk, not an example code of how to use the FLAG_IMMUTABLE for a PendingIntent. I will update my question for more clarification