# shows error 31008 while doing client to client call in Twilio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, twilio

I am making an android app for client to client call using Twilio. I have cloned this repository. https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android

I followed all steps for **alice** an one client. Made an app and installed in one device. then I didn't changed the **Server** file code especially from **place-call.js** & **make-call.js**

First three lines of place-call is

```
const callerNumber = '+1 4243471xxx';
const callerId = 'client:alice';
const defaultIdentity = 'alice';
```

Now keeping all this things same because I have only one Twilio phone number, in-order to make another client app instance for **bob** I just did step 7 by replacing **identity** from **alice** to **bob** from GitHub repo which is.

> ```
> $ twilio api:chat:v2:credentials:create \
>     --type=fcm \
>     --friendly-name="voice-push-credential-fcm" \
>     --secret=SERVER_KEY_VALUE
> ```
>
> This will return a Push Credential SID that looks like this
>
> ```
> CRxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> ```
>
> Now let's generate another access
> token and add the Push Credential to the Voice Grant.
>
> ```
> $ twilio
> token:voice \
>     --identity=bob \
>     --voice-app-sid=APxxxx \
>     --push-credential-sid=CRxxxxs
> ```

And made the another instance of app. Now whenever I call from **alice** app client to **bob** client then I recieve the muted notification and when accept then shows **error 31008**

Screenshot of my call history is

[call-logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpPez.png)

Why it shows incoming from **alice**? Because I am doing call **alice** to **bob**

Can I make two client having single Twilio phone number?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67046334/9046638)

Comment: You used the tag for Java but your code seems to be JavaScript. Please fix the tags.

Comment: @aled actually it is an android app made using Java. But the functions of server side was written in JavaScript

Comment: @aled once check it out that GitHub repo